# Use OpenMesh to get the texture maps of textured mesh

Tags: c++, mesh, sampling, point-clouds, openmesh

I use OpenMesh to get the texture maps  of textured mesh, but it does not work.

```
OpenMesh::MPropHandleT< std::map< int, std::string > > textures_files;
mesh.get_property_handle(textures_files, "TextureMapping");
std::cout << "textures_files" << textures_files << std::endl;
```

the following is my .ply mesh data

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment Generated by the CGAL library
comment TextureFile Tile_+1984_+2688_0.jpg
comment label 0 unclassified
comment label 1 ground
comment label 2 vegetation
comment label 3 building
comment label 4 water
comment label 5 car
comment label 6 boat
element vertex 156580
property double x
property double y
property double z
element face 309445
property list uchar int vertex_indices
property int label
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property list uchar float texcoord
property int texnumber
property int face_segment_id
property float label_probabilities
end_header
6148.180 4118.970 10.86990 
6147.150 4119.200 12.75190 
6147.670 4118.100 14.33410
```

I use these codes, the output always is -1, meanging that the codes can not the the texture maps.